# Яндекс Карты и выпадающее меню вне ее границ

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не могу понять как вытащить дропдаун из карты, options.position двигает за края и он уезжает из видимости.
Надо дропдаун внутри карты поставить в положение дропдауна вне карты.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Если это элемент управления карты, то в целом никак. Эти элементы действительно позиционируются внутри контейнера карты.